# ロードバランサー用サーバーの Linux カーネルパラメータのチューニングについて

Tags: linux

この度、新しいサーバーを購入したのでLinux(CentOS)でカーネルパラメータのチューニングを行いたいと思っております。

/etc/sysctl.confに色々と記述していきたいのですが

> ・カーネルパラメータの種類は全部でどのくらいあってどこかで公開されているのか？
>   （sysctl -a で表示されるパラメータ以外にも存在していて設定できるのかどうか？）
>
> ・boolean(true or false)以外の値として利用するパラメータの場合、なかには上限値はサーバースペック等によって決まってくるものもあるかと思いますがその値はどうやって決めればいいのか？

この2点で困っております。

サーバー用途としては、LVS(ロードバランサー)させる予定なので
「ファイルへのアクセスが多くなる」というよりは、「トラフィックの量が増える」のでネットワーク周りで有利になるようなオプションを多数見つけて設定したいです。

ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドキュメントとしてはこの辺でしょうか
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/

後は /proc の下を探す、カーネルのソースコードを読む、等があると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
サーバースペックに依存するような上限値については適当な値をいれてみて、運用しながら様子をみつつ増やしたり減らしたりしていこうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

基本的なことはこちらで網羅されているかと思います。
Redhatの資料ですが、他のDistributionでも応用可能です。https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/20150325_network_performance_tuning.pdf

トラフィックの特性によって不足するリソースが異なるので、あとは負荷試験とチューニングの繰り返しです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせて頂きます。